# Foucault's measurements of the speed of light

Tags: experimental-physics, speed-of-light, rotation, history

I understand that you can — in principle — measure the speed of light with the rotating mirror experiment.

What I don't understand:  How can you accurately measure (or fix) the number of rotations of the mirror per second?  I mean, it has to be really, really fast.

Comment: wikipedia has a pretty good description.

Comment: @nielsnielsen The question is about measurement and/or calibration of the rotation rate of the mirror. The wikipedia article does not contain information on how Foucault monitored the rotation rate of the mirror.

Comment: Hmm? I did this experiment at school when I was sixteen.

Comment: @SuzuHirose So, what do you want to say with this?

Comment: You seemed to be suggesting that you don't understand how this could be done in the present day, and I thought it was strange since it's a typical school experiment. If you were referring to the historical experiment then that is something else of course. Anyway we have a very interesting answer below. I'm not going to discuss further.

Comment: @SuzuHirose Interesting. So how did you measure the number of rotations per second in school?

Comment: So easy now - [Pasco Complete Speed of Light Apparatus](https://cdn.pasco.com/product_document/Complete-Speed-of-Light-Apparatus-Manual-OS-9261B-OS-9262A-OS-9263B.pdf)

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/263923/how-did-fizeau-control-the-cogs-rotational-speed

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Foucault published the results of his rotating mirror experiments in
Comptes rendus hebdomadaires des séances de l'Académie des sciences, [Compt. Rend. 55, 792 (1862)](https://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/item/23649#page/798/mode/1up0).
Foucault's account of the rotating mirror part of the experiment goes like this after a Google translation into English.

> Let us first say how one impresses on the mirror a constant speed.
> This silver glass mirror, which is 14 millimetres in diameter, is
> mounted directly on the axis of a small air turbine of a known system,
> admirably executed by M. Froment. The air is supplied by a
> high-pressure blower from Mr. Cavaillé-Coll, who has acquired a just
> reputation in the manufacture of large organs. As it is important that
> the pressure be very fixed, on leaving the wind tunnel the air passes
> through a regulator recently designed by Mr. Cavaillé and in which the
> pressure does not vary by a millimetre over 30 centimetres of column
> of water. By flowing through the orifices of the turbine, the fluid
> therefore represents a remarkably constant driving force.

> On the other hand, the mirror in accelerating soon encounters in the
> ambient air a resistance which for a given speed is also perfectly
> constant. The moving object placed between these two contrary forces
> which tend to equilibrium cannot fail to take up and keep a uniform
> speed. Any obturator acting on the flow of the air, moreover, enables
> this speed to be regulated within very wide limits.

[image]

Thus Foucault has a rotating mirror arrangement driven by compressed air (he first used steam) the speed of which he could adjust and he was confident that the speed of rotation could be kept constant.

> Finally, it remained to count the number of revolutions, or rather to
> impart to the moving body a determined speed. This issue has been
> completely resolved as follows: Between the microscope and the mirror
> with partial reflection is a circular disc, the finely toothed edge of
> which encroaches on the image which one observes and intercepts it in
> part; the disc rotates uniformly on itself, so that if the image were
> to shine continuously, the teeth which it bears on its circumference
> would escape sight by the rapidity of the movement. But the image is
> not permanent, it results from a series of discontinuous appearances
> which are in number equal to that of the revolutions of the mirror,
> and in the particular case where the teeth of the screen also follow
> one another in the same number, there is produced for the eye an
> illusion easy to explain, which makes the teeth reappear as if the
> disc were not turning.

Foucault used the strobe effect to measure the speed of his mirror and to check the constancy of its speed of revolution.

> Suppose then that this disc bearing n teeth on
> its circumference makes one revolution per second and that at the same
> time the turbine is started; if by adjusting the flow of driving air
> we manage to maintain the apparent fixity of the teeth, we can take it
> for certain that the mirror actually makes n revolutions per second.
> M. Froment, who had made the turbine, kindly undertook to compose and
> construct a chronometric train to move the disc; it is a very
> remarkable piece of timepiece, which elegantly solves the problem of
> uniform motion in the particular case where there is no work to be
> done. Success is so complete, that every day I happen to spin the
> mirror at 400 rotations per second and see the two devices working
> together at near 1/10000 whole minutes.

[image]

The disc at the front of the apparatus (adapted clock) had 400 teeth on it and rotated at exactly one revolution per second.  Thus the first stationary position of the teeth when viewed in reflected light from the rotating mirror was when the mirror rotated at $400$ revolutions per second. One can tell how pleased he was with the arrangement on reading the last sentence.

Comment: Did someone (Foucault or an assistant?) have to manually pump the high-pressure blower?

Comment: Yes, it apparently was a [bellows arrangement](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ad5WdZBiLoc) made by a man who was very good at making bellows for organs. Note the organ pedals in the video.  As the other answer from @Cloenis shows there are artifacts from the original experiment and modern reproductions but not such (visual) detail in the original paper.

Answer (score 4):

I found a blog post, on a blog by the 'Ecole Polytechnique' of Paris, France.

Title:
[l’appareil de Foucault pour mesurer la vitesse de la lumière](https://portail.polytechnique.edu/musx/fr/decembre-2019-lappareil-de-foucault-pour-mesurer-la-vitesse-de-la-lumiere)
*Foucault's apparatus for measuring the speed of light*

I copied the relevant paragraph into Google Translate:

> Conversely, measuring the rotational speed of the mirror is more complex. This is where Foucault's ingenuity comes in by setting up a clockwork movement (photo). This device has a toothed wheel (outside) with a speed of 400 revolutions per second. The wheel is then placed between the viewfinder and the return light so that when the mirror (which reflects the final light beam) and the wheel reach the same speed, the wheel appears motionless by a stroboscopic effect.

<s>So the measurment involved an extraordinary custom built clock. The clock had to have the accuracy necessary for the measurement, and it had to have enough raw strength to drive an axle (with a small wheel at the end) at a rotation rate of 400 revolutions per second.</s>

CORRECTION:
The custon built clock had a axle rotating at one revolution per second, the disk on that axle had 400 teeth. One revolution per second still requires a custom clock, but it is quite doable.

I made this correction after reading the answer by contributor Farcher. Farcher found a better information source than I had.

Also available: two youtube videos on the 'Musée des Arts et Métiers' youtube channel

The revolving mirror was air driven:
[Foucault et la mesure de la vitesse de la lumière, 1862 - Le miroir tournant](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ad5WdZBiLoc)

How the mirrors and the sight were arranged:
[Foucault et la mesure de la vitesse de la lumière, 1862](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QV0YZRVXnYE)

Comment: This was one of the experiments at my school so I don't think it's particularly extraordinary technology to do that.

Comment: @SuzuHirose High-precision, high-strength clockworks were much less available in the 1860s than today.

Comment: The question here seems to be in the present tense, not actually concerning the historical experiment but the entire principle of measuring these rotations, yet this is a common school experiment. Anyway I didn't see that the question was about the historical experiment.

Comment: @Cleonis I would not worry about your minor error as one would expect a source such as  École polytechnique to be authoritative?!

Comment: @SuzuHirose Seems like the title of the question specifically refers to the measurements of Foucault.

Comment: @Tom - I've re-read the question and it doesn't seem like that, the questioner seems to be asserting that in the present he cannot see how this could be done. Obviously interpretations of words can vary but I don't think that my reading of the question was obviously incorrect. Let's drop the topic now.

Comment: I did the experiment in high school. We measured the speed by the sound frequency it made, sometimes I had students who could judge the sound exactly, other times we compared it to a tuning fork

Comment: @trula Well, nowadays a manufacturer of tuning forks can tune the fork to within a Hertz or so. In 1860: if you wanted a tuning fork you had to manufacture it yourself. Incidentally, according to the video on the 'Musée des Arts et Métiers' youtube channel about the [light speed measurement](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ad5WdZBiLoc) the setup included a small organ pipe and a tuning fork. It could be that  Foucault used the organ pipe to rough in the rotation rate as the mirror was being spun up. Foucault would have to tune the tuning fork himself, using the custom clock as reference.

Comment: I think the question is for to days experiments.

Comment: @trula After the introduction of Maxwell's theory of electromagnetism the approach to measuring the speed of light shifted to interferometry. First interferometry with radio waves, later interferometry with electromagnetic waves in the visible spectrum. Web page by the 'Science Ready' organisation with historical information; [How Light's Speed was Determined](https://scienceready.com.au/pages/determination-of-speed-of-light). The rotating mirror setup is of historical importance only.

Comment: many historical experiments are important for school kids. you can explain Foucaults experiment without knowing of interference which you learn much later, and Foucaults experiment ist part of many  experimental lectures  in university! (at least in Germany)